# Не рисует на canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Помогите, я решил попробовать написать игру на `Javascript` в своей игре я оспользую некоторое подобие ООП и вот когда я хочу сказать методу `Draw` из класса `Drawable` он отказывается рисовать, почему? Однако свойство, например `fillStyle` изменилось но квадрат не нарисовался.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("Game");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Drawable = {
  Draw: function(params) {
    console.log(params.ctx); //Пишет что это контест Canvas

    params.ctx.fillStyle = params.fillStyle || params.ctx.fillStyle;
    params.ctx.fillRect(params.x, params.y, params.width, params.height); //Но не рисует


  }
}

var Player = {
  Player: function() {

  },
  MoveAt: function(degree) {
    degree = degree || this.degree;
    this.x += Math.sin(degree) * this.speed;
    this.y += Math.cos(degree) * this.speed;
  },
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  speed: 10,
  degree: 0,
}

var MainPlayer = new Player.Player();
Drawable.Draw({
  ctx: ctx,
  fillStyle: "red",
  x: MainPlayer.x,
  y: MainPlayer.y,
  width: 30,
  height: 60,

});
```

```html
<canvas id="Game"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у вас `x` и `y` - `undefined`.

Comment: Да уже разобрался, спасибо поэтому мне плюсы больше нравятся